# Should there be a modification to this off-topic criterion?

Tags: discussion

One of the reasons that can be given for flagging a question as off topic includes the following.

> This question appears to be off-topic because it requires step-by-step instructions for a process that is specific to a particular project, and/or demonstrates too little effort on the part of the asker. ...

There are times when I have been preparing an answer that I've aborted the process of answering because I've come to perceive that the best answers to their question will fall afoul of the above criterion. Now, for most of the blenderheads participating in BlenderSE, this doesn't bother me, but there is a class of user who is obviously a novice (or less) at blender, for which I find the reputation of the users in that class on the site to be an effective, if slightly inaccurate indicator and I feel that not answering, is unfriendly, and perhaps reflects poorly on the Blender community. So I'd like to propose two actions. First, a grant of reputation (perhaps 250 points), or maybe a badge to a user who can demonstrate completion of either Chronister's or Hirsig's on-line courses in Blender, or a similar equivalent.

The second action would be to not declare a question from a user who has a reputation below a certain value (again, 250 points is a suggestion) off topic for this reason. Especially since, on the one hand, I don't see that many questions which would seem to be off topic on this criterion, and on the other hand, some questons which should be flagged as of topic on this basis are answered anyway.

Answer (score 2):

First is is not possible to grant users rep (out side of bounties). Also it is not a good idea to grant new users rep based on *blender* experience, because the SE rep system is in part measuring how well a user knows the *site*.

If you want to answer a question that you think may be on the edge of being off topic for "too specific", I would suggest you go ahead and answer it.

However if it is clearly off topic please do not answer it (as it will encourage more of the same.)

I agree with you that this is not the best CV reason (and we are working to reword the CV reason) . It is quite subjective, some questions get answered (with lots of UV) and others are just closed and left to sit.